# magento default config values for storeview

Tags: configuration, stores

I understand that you can set default store config values by using the syntax

```
<default>
    <path>
        <to>
            <config>value</config>
        </to>
    </path>
</default>
```

but i am also pretty certain that it is possible to set default values for individual store views in config.xml also .  Without the need to set manually in admin or by using an upgrade script.

Is it possible?

I have tried

```
<storecode>
    <path>
        <to>
            <config>value</config>
        </to>
    </path>
</storecode>
```

but that didnt work

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217043/magento-setting-admin-configuration-values-for-store-view-scope-via-xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the answer in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217043/magento-setting-admin-configuration-values-for-store-view-scope-via-xml) question says you need some another node surrounding your code. When you wrap your code with `<stores>` and then it will work.

```
<default>
    <some>
        <config>
            <value>default</value>
        </config>
    </some>
</default>
<stores>
    <your_store_code>
        <some>
            <config>
                <value>something</value>
            </config>
        </some>
    </your_store_code>
</stores>
```

Answer (score 5):

The same is also possible for websites:

```
<websites>
    <your_website_code>
        <some>
            <config>
                <value>something</value>
            </config>
        </some>
    </your_website_code>
</websites>
```